# Laravel model not routing to the view

Tags: laravel

I created a new model called ProjectsController and want to have it route to views/projects/index.blade.php.

This is my ProjectsController code:

```
class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('projects.index');
    }
}
```

And the path is correct for the file as in resources/views/projects/index.blade.php.

However, my /projects page gives this error:
`"View [projects.index] not found."`

Route web.php is:
`Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectsController@index');`

Comment: Have you tried to do `php artisan optimize:clear` in the terminal from the root of your laravel installation?

Answer (score 1):

ProjectsController is a Controller, not a Model just FYI.  Definitely check the docs for further clarification there.

Please confirm that you have your view in the right place and named correctly like so:

`/resources/views/projects/index.blade.php`

I have never seen Laravel throw a View not found error when the view is present in the correct location.

Comment: I solved it out. Don't know why that really happened, but my thought is that PhpStorm caused some kind of error when creating the file or directory into views/. I am using sFTP for live editing.

After deleting everything and creating the inex.blade.php file with cli, everything went well.